# Advanced attribute is not working in magento2

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

I have created one custom product attribute as `text field` and that attribute is working fine and it's coming in product options. But i want to set one default text for all products, for that i have added `Default Value` in `Advanced Attribute Properties` ,but that value is not coming in that attribute option in product adding page.

Comment: screen shot please

Comment: find the screenshot here-- https://prnt.sc/gv66wr

Comment: Please try it without html code firsly!!